# How can I add value to a private variable in a class?

Tags: c#, oop, variables, object

I have a class that I declared 4 private variables. User enter 3 variable and the fourth one is an average value of 3 first variables. I don't know how can I assign the average value to the object.

```
class grade {
double grade_1;
double grade_2;
double grade_3;
double avg;

public void input(){
grade_1 = console.readline();
grade_2 = console.readline();
grade_3 = console.readline();
}

public double cal_avg() {
 avg = 0;
 avg = (grade_1+ grade_2+ grade_3)/3;
 return avg;
}
}

//.........

grade obj_grade = new grade();
obj_grade.input();
double avg = obj_grade.cal_avg;
```

ok at this step, I got avg but I don't know to assign it to my object's fourth variable. Any idea? Thanks.

Also, is there a way to call a private variable in a class?

Comment: This code doesn't look like it would compile (`console.readline()` should be `Console.ReadLine()`, `cal_avg` is a method but is used like a property). Do you have some working code?

Comment: @vesan: I know, I typed it for a quick question. I didn't copy my code from visual studio.

Comment: @LouisTran - Please don't post code that you haven't tested first. Make sure you only copy working code. You should read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Please when upvoting make sure to fix post to not have errors outside of what OP is asking for. Note that you need 3K+ reputation to do so as code  changes rarely are ok and will be rejected if your change is reviewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void setToRes(double d) {
    this.avg = d;
}
```

Use a method to set it to the private value declared at the start of the class.

You could modify this

```
public double cal_avg() {
 avg = 0;
 avg = (grade_1+ grade_2+ grade_3)/3;
 return avg;
}
```

To look like this

```
public double cal_avg() {
 return (grade_1+ grade_2+ grade_3)/3;
}
```

And then use either

```
this.avg = cal_avg();
```

Or use my method

```
setToRes(cal_avg());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `avg` already has the value set because `cal_avg()` uses it.